# Reshaping World Bank Data

Tags: r

Trying to run analysis on WB data (in .xlsx form), however the data is not ready for regression. Currently each row contains data on a different country, and each column is data for a specific year.

Ideally, I'd like to create a new sheet/data table of three columns: Country, Year and MeanValue. Each row of MeanValue would equal the mean value for each year column in the original sheet.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the `wbstats` package (I think there are others that facilitate obtaining World Bank data as well).  That way you can access the data directly in to R.  For example, to obtain data for all countries on GPD at market prices in current US dollars from 2000 to 2016:

```
dt <- wbstats::wb(indicator = "NY.GDP.MKTP.CD", startdate = 2000, enddate = 2016)
```

Then you just need to select the columns you want to keep, for example using `dplyr` like this:

```
library(dplyr)

 dt <- tbl_df(dt)
 dt %>%  arrange(country, date) %>% select(country, date, value)
Source: local data frame [3,441 x 3]

       country  date       value
         (chr) (chr)       (dbl)
1  Afghanistan  2001  2461666315
2  Afghanistan  2002  4128818042
3  Afghanistan  2003  4583648922
4  Afghanistan  2004  5285461999
5  Afghanistan  2005  6275076016
6  Afghanistan  2006  7057598407
7  Afghanistan  2007  9843842455
8  Afghanistan  2008 10190529882
9  Afghanistan  2009 12486943506
10 Afghanistan  2010 15936800636
..         ...   ...         ...
```

I'm not sure what you want when you refer to the mean value, because if you are keeping a row for each country and year then there isn't anything to take the mean over.